# How much do I need to sleep?

Tags: health, sleep

I'm a 16 years old guy and I'm not getting enough time to complete my daily jobs. So, I decided to cut my sleep but after reading a few articles it seem not to be a good option.

I used to sleep 8 hrs approx.. 
Now I want to cut it to 6 hrs,
after trying it for one day, I realised that I  was not feeling good that day and I was feeling a slight weakness. 
Is it normal  if I change mmy schedule?
How much do I need to sleep?
Please  suggest the least time possible with no side - effects.

Comment: You are still growing, have plenty of sleep.

Comment: have plenty of sleep as much as possible. Make the most of it while you're young.

Comment: @Ker I can't waste time on sleeping, I've much  to do.

Comment: @Hritik as a 16 year old, growing is your most important job, i had a pretty hectic childhood too, and my days are still pretty long, but i always find time to sleep 8-9 hours, and so will you

Comment: @s3v3ns How old are you? If you get 8-9 hours regularly, you must be pretty young.

Comment: @Hritik you're not wasting time sleeping. because you NEED it. just plan what you need to do ahead of time so you can be more efficient.

Comment: @Mephisto, Well if you workout hard, you will sleep more. At the moment I am taking a little break, and i can feel that i don't need more than 8 hours. But to answer your question, i'am in my twenties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every person is different, but there is a simple way to gauge your personal sleep needs. You need an alarm clock, a notebook and two weeks.

1. Set the alarm clock at the very same hour each day (including sunday).
2. Avoid caffeine and naps.
3. Each morning write down the approximate hours you went to bed and the hour you felt asleep the night before.
4. If the alarm clock woke you up today, go to bed tonight half an hour earlier than yesterday.
5. There comes a day when you wake up *a bit* earlier than the clock. Go on with the experiment and go to bed half an hour earlier than the day before anyway. If you wake up one hour or so earlier than the alarm, don't subtract half an hour to bedtime any more.
6. There comes a day in which you notice that you have woken up at least one full hour earlier than the clock for *several days in a row* and the amount of hours you have slept each of those days is approximately uniform. **That is the amount of sleep time you need.** Allowing yourself any less than that means poor quality of life. Trying to sleep more than that *on average* will be impossible.

For the record, I did the experience when I was 15 yr and it was ~8h15min. I have repeated it at 42 yr and now it is ~6h20min.

Don't cut down on sleep time. You may apparently win some hours, but during the hours you spend awake you will be a different person: one that is less intelligent, less optimist, emotionally less stable, more prone to pesimistic thoughts, and much more. Go and have as much sleep as you need.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be a good way, just the last line is a little troublesome :)
Anyways, I'll try this and report here

Comment: @Hritik Why? Btw, after the experience, you may want to try poliphasic sleep, that is sleeping less hours during the night but having a nap *exactly at the same time* every day. Many people do that and they say it works for them, but you will have to commit yourself never to skip the nap.

Answer (score 0):

It is very personal, there have been people in history who only needed to sleep 4 hours per night, some people can get by with 6 hours, but most need about 8. You need as many as makes you feel rested.

You'll have to try different amounts and see what works for you.

Comment: I want to know about side effects.

Comment: headache, joints pain, lack of concentration etc as other suggested sleep atleast 7-8 hours. if you dont fulfill the needs of your body than your body doesnt fill your needs.

Comment: That was very well put, Vikas :)

Comment: Will 7Hrs be considered good for my age ?

Comment: @Hritik - Every person is different. 7 hours is "good" for any age, but it may be more than you personally need, or it may not be enough. We can't tell you either way. If you are concerned about your sleep and general health, I would suggest you talk with a doctor and possibly get a referral for sleep studies.

Comment: @Hritik One of the side effects you definitely don't want is low testosterone and growth hormone levels.

Comment: What will be the symptoms that less sleep is affecting me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something about your daily jobs. If you find the time to get 8 hours of sleep, then your work schedule is not healthy and you are bound to get into trouble sooner or later regardless of whether or not you actually get enough sleep. I would suggest that you stick to at least 8 hours of sleep. In fact, at your age 9 hours should be better. Also you need to do about one hour exercise per day.